# PIE disabled. Absolute addressing error! IOS 7

Tags: ios7, xcode5

After upgrading to mountain lion with xcode 4.5 and unity 4.0.1, from snow leopard and unity 3.5, having this issue - PIE disabled. Absolute addressing I went through all forum and got no answer for this. i reinstall all, still same error (which come with obsolete device location services error, but i managed to get rid of this on...) Still this PIE error is not letting me continue, i can archive and send to App Store only to be rejected. PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> in xcode 5.0 build settings change "Dont create position independent executables" from NO to Yes, thats it. after so much trouble..

Comment: can we not rather enable _OPENSSL_rdtsc to use relative addressing?